# Using jquery to preset html tickbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

This code,

```
$("#x").removeAttr("checked").removeAttr("unchecked").attr("foo","bar");
```

Results in this html input:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="x" foo="bar">
```

And yet this:

```
$("#x").removeAttr("checked").removeAttr("unchecked").attr("checked","true");
```

Results in this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="x" checked="checked">
```

What is going on? Despite this checked="checked" attribute, the checkbox still remains stubbornly unchecked.

What is the best way to toggle the checked attribute of an HTML input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To toggle checked use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`:

```
$('#x').prop('checked',true);
$('#x').prop('checked',false);
```

If you want another button to toggle the checkbox you can use:

```
var $x  = $('#x'); // don't query every click - Credit: Roko :) 
$('.button').click(function(){      
    $x.prop('checked', !$x.is(':checked'));
})
```

Comment: `$('.button').click(function(){
    var $x  = $('#x'); // don't query twice!` *"don't query twice"*... But also don't query every time you click.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've updated and gave you credit :), I believe in a real website #x will be more dynamic.. button for each checkbox or something like that.. But you are obviously right.

Answer (score 1):

`checked="true"` is incorrect HTML so JQuery is implicitly converting it to `checked="checked"`.  The other answer has provided a better solution since it is unnecessary to use `removeAttr` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#x')[0].checked = true; // true / false
```

http://jsbin.com/ivufen/1/edit

## toggle:

```
var $cbx = $('#x')[0];

$('#toggle').click(function(){
  $cbx.checked = !$cbx.checked;
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ivufen/3/edit